# Metro 2033 and Last Light (Redux editions) not loading

Tags: opengl

I purchased Metro Last Light and 2033 earlier today, and was hoping to play them, however whenever I try they tell me I need Open GL 4.0 or higher.  I believe I have the latest drivers, and I could really use some help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you have OpenGL 4 support depends on your hardware and drivers.  If you use the open-source graphics stack, which I suspect you are, you do not have OpenGL 4 support because mesa does not support it.  If you use Intel's integrated graphics, you have no choice but to use the open-source drivers and you cannot play these games.  If you have an nvidia or radeon card you will need to install the proprietary drivers in order to play.